# PostgreSQL - how to insert into array of composite type

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```sql
CREATE TYPE myenum AS ENUM ('title', 'link', 'text');
CREATE TYPE struct AS (
            type myenum,
            content varchar(300)
        );
CREATE TABLE "mytable" (
            id serial PRIMARY KEY,
            array struct[]
        );
INSERT INTO "mytable" VALUES (
            DEFAULT,
            '{"(\"title\",\"my title\")","(\"link\",\"www.google.com\")"}'
        );
INSERT INTO "mytable" VALUES (
            DEFAULT,
            ARRAY['(\"title\",\"my title\")', '(\"link\",\"www.google.com\")']
        );
INSERT INTO "mytable" VALUES (
            DEFAULT,
            ARRAY[('title','my title'), ('link','www.google.com')]
        );
```

i want to insert some data , and i tried many forms but they all can't insert success,
and there are some error messages

```
error: malformed array literal: "{"("title","my title")","("link","www.google.com")"}"
error: malformed array literal: "{("title","my title"), ("link","www.google.com")}"
error: column "placeholder_array" is of type placeholder_struct[] but expression is of type text[]
error: column "placeholder_array" is of type placeholder_struct[] but expression is of type record[]
```

need helppppp!
that's so hard and messy for me, thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). Don't call your column `array`, that's a keyword.

2). Use `::struct` to cast your tuples to that datatype.

```
CREATE TYPE myenum AS ENUM ('title', 'link', 'text');

CREATE TYPE struct AS (
            type myenum,
            content varchar(300)
        );

CREATE TABLE mytable (
            id serial PRIMARY KEY,
            val_array struct[]
        );

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (
            DEFAULT,
            ARRAY[('title','my title')::struct, ('link','www.google.com')::struct]
        );
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c0749fa5868c7b6553c17cf823dd1073)

Comment: the first question is because i just show it clearly, its name is not array actually, AND the second also MOST IMPORTANT , it does works!!  thank you!!!